# VBA Register Cell Copy Change Action and Change Column Values

Tags: excel, vba

I have a problem with registering mass cells update by users. Let's say my table looks like this:

[image]

Column `A` is to register changes that happens in column `C`. I came up with a solution like this:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal target As Range)
...
    Set intersection = Intersect(target, Range("C2:C9"))

    If Not intersection Is Nothing Then
        CurrentValue = target.Value
        With Application
            .EnableEvents = False
            .Undo
            If target.Value <> CurrentValue Then
                target.Value = CurrentValue
                ' Handle A column input
                If InStr(Range("A" & target.Row).Value, ", item group changed") = 0 Then
                    Range("A" & target.Row).Value = Range("A" & target.Row).Value & ", item group changed"
                End If
            End If
            .EnableEvents = True
        End With
    End If
```

The problem is that it only works if a user manually changes cell by cell in range in column `C`. I want this macro to be able to detect, for example, if the user pastes something into range `C2:C5` or drags value from `C2` to `C5`, etc. to update cells `A2:A5` accordingly with the information that something happened there. Is it possible?

Comment: how about storing the range into an array then comparing each cell row to each array row if not equal then you can label the change in column A same row

Comment: @k1dr0ck I'm not sure if I know what you mean. Do you mean i should store all C column values into array and then in Worksheet Change function iterate over them all and compare current state ? If so, that wont work as i will have over 200k values in each Column and that would take forever i believe.

Comment: Your code checks for `intersection` but then goes on to work directly with `Target` (which could well include cells *not* in your area of interest)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Handling multi-cell `Target` cases is a bit more difficult than the single-cell case.

**EDIT**: updated to handle non-contiguous (>1 `Area`) `Target` ranges.

You could do it like this for example though:

Need to create a small Class to store information about a range:

```
'Class module "AreaData"
Option Explicit
Public rng As Range
Public values As Variant
```

Main code in sheet module:

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim newValues As Collection, newIsectValues As Collection
    Dim intersection As Range, c As Range, oldIsectValues As Collection
    Dim rw As Long, col As Long, i As Long, oldAD As AreaData, newAD As AreaData
    
    Set intersection = Intersect(Target, Me.Range("C3:C15"))  'check area of interest...
    If intersection Is Nothing Then Exit Sub                  'no cells in area of interest
    
    On Error GoTo haveError
    
    Set newValues = GetRangeData(Target)             'current info for the whole Target range
    Set newIsectValues = GetRangeData(intersection)  'current info for intersect only
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Application.Undo                                 'restore previous values
    Set oldIsectValues = GetRangeData(intersection)  'grab the old intersect range info
    
    RestoreRange newValues                           'restore the whole Target range...
        
    'Check each new vs old value in the intersection range
    '  (for each area if not contiguous)
    For i = 1 To newIsectValues.Count
        Set newAD = newIsectValues(i)
        Set oldAD = oldIsectValues(i)
        For rw = 1 To UBound(newAD.values, 1)
            For col = 1 To UBound(newAD.values, 2)
                If newAD.values(rw, col) <> oldAD.values(rw, col) Then
                    Set c = newAD.rng.Cells(rw, col)
                    c.EntireRow.Columns("A").Value = "Group changed from " & oldAD.values(rw, col)
                End If
            Next col
        Next rw
    Next i 'next area
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Exit Sub
    
haveError:
    MsgBox Err.Description
    If Not Application.EnableEvents Then Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub

'restore a range's values from a Collection of `AreaData` objects
Sub RestoreRange(rangeData As Collection)
    Dim ad As AreaData
    For Each ad In rangeData       'loop the Areas
        ad.rng.Value = ad.values   'restore values
    Next ad
End Sub

'capture info about a [possibly multi-area] range and its value(s)
Function GetRangeData(rng As Range) As Collection
    Dim a As Range, rv As New Collection
    For Each a In rng.Areas
        rv.Add GetAreaData(a)
    Next a
    Set GetRangeData = rv
End Function

'store info about a contiguous range in an instance of the type `AreaData`
Function GetAreaData(rng As Range) As AreaData
    Set GetAreaData = New AreaData
    Set GetAreaData.rng = rng
    GetAreaData.values = RangeToArray(rng)
End Function

'get a 2D array from a range, handling the single-cell case
Function RangeToArray(rng As Range) As Variant
    Dim arr(1 To 1, 1 To 1)
    If rng.CountLarge = 1 Then
        arr(1, 1) = rng.Value
        RangeToArray = arr
    Else
        RangeToArray = rng.Value
    End If
End Function
```

**Note**: you should not use this approach if `Target` might
contain cells with formulas, since those would be over-written with values by `Target.Value = newValue`

Comment: I will verify it tuesday after easter holiday and I'll sure flag it if it will work for me :)

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work for me. When i drag for example From C2 to C7 with filtered rows so for example C2 C5 C7 are only visible, value is written into cells C but no message on corresponding cell in A column shows :(

Comment: If you have a filtered table then likely a drag-fill gives you a multi-area `Target` range. `If Target.Areas.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub` means if Target has >1 area then it won't try to process that change.  It's already tricky with a single-area range: adding in multi-area makes it much more difficult.

Comment: On testing it does seem to work for me when drag-filling in a filtered table: in this case `Target` is a single area, and the value in ColA is populated as expected.  It will not work if you select across multiple rows and then enter a value using Ctrl+Enter, because that creates a multi-area `Target`

Comment: See update above - should now handle multi-area ranges correctly.