# Mismatch error 13 in Ubound when entering a single value

Tags: excel, vba

My code works how I want it to work, but when I have to put a single value, it shows error 13, and I don't really know why. I think it is because you can't use ubound in a single value array, but I don't know how to solve or replace it

I tried using an If that when I have a single value it just uses another variable, but it didn't work, and I don't really think that's a solution.

```vb
 Dim material As Variant, cantidad As Variant
    Dim g As Long, lastrow As Long, cant As Long
    Dim wsCarg As Worksheet, wsRem As Worksheet, wb As Workbook, wsDev As Worksheet
   
   
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook 'for example
    Set wsCarg = wb.Worksheets("CARGA")
    Set wsRem = wb.Worksheets("REMITO")
    Set wsDev = wb.Worksheets("DEVOLUCIONES")
    
    lastrow = wsRem.Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row
    material = wsRem.Range("C28:C" & lastrow).Value
    cantidad = wsRem.Range("M28:M" & lastrow).Value
    g = UBound(material, 1) 'number of rows of data
```

This is the part of the code which has an error, if you can suggest anything I will appreciate it, sorry for my English, and thanks in advance!

Comment: You can either check if `wsRem.Range("C28:C" & lastrow).CountLarge = 1`, or if `lastrow = 28`. If you're working with  a single cell, then you need to create an array yourself. See [this](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/ArraysAndRanges.aspx), about halfway down.

Comment: Dim material() as Variant. This declares an array. And also for cantidad

Comment: BigBen answer worked just fine, and i didnt realized it didnt have the brackets, thanks for the answers!

Comment: @Blackcat: If you declare `Dim material() as Variant`, you declare an array of variants. If you then write `material = wsRem.Range("C28:C" & lastrow).Value` and lastrow = 28, you will get a type mismatch.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Range.Value` returns always a 2-dimensional array with the values (even if you have only one row or one column of data). **Except** if the range contains only one cell, in that case it simply returns the value itself (not as array).

There are many ways to check this:

Use the property `Count` (or, even better `CountLarge` to avoid overflows) of the range. Note that this will work only correctly if you have only one Column as it counts the total number of cells of the range (rows * columns)

```
g = wsRem.Range("C28:C" & lastrow).CountLarge
```

You can use the `Rows.Count`-property of the Range

```
g = wsRem.Range("C28:C" & lastrow).Rows.Count
```

You could compare `lastrow` with the starting row. I would suggest to use a constant definition:

```
Const startRow = 28
material = wsRem.Range("C" & startRow & ":C" & lastrow).Value
g = lastRow - startRow + 1
```

You can check if the returned value is an array:

```
If IsArray(material) Then 
    g = UBound(material, 1)
Else
    g = 1
End If
```

However, when you process the data (eg `material`), it might come handy to convert it to a 2-dimensional array with 1*1 elements when it contains only a single value. With that, you don't have to take care if you deal with an array or not in the following code, eg

```
If Not isArray(material) Then
    Dim tmpVal As Variant
    tmpVal = material
    Redim material(1 to 1, 1 to 1)
    material(1, 1) = tmpVal
End If
```

Comment: You can wrap this up in a function - eg. `RangeToArray` here  - https://stackoverflow.com/a/75960364/478884